# jQuery does not behave properly. Using jquery.turbolinks in Rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using [jquery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). Each page uses countdown to display time until a specific time. But the values on the countdown does not change correctly as switching among pages through link_to, correct values are shown only after refresh. Same problem happens to other jQuery as well.

Using [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks), did not solve my problem. Did exactly as instructed, added `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'`
to gem file, and my application.js file is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.plugin
//= require jquery.countdown
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

Any though what could possibly go wrong? Thanks in advance!

---

Initially I have:

```
$(function () {
    var endTime = new Date( <%= end_time(@item).to_i * 1000 %> );
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: endTime
    });
});
```

After reading some posts I changed this to:

```
var ready;
ready = function () {
    var endTime = new Date( <%= end_time(@item).to_i * 1000 %> );
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: endTime
    });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Still does not work.

---

UPDATE:

Don't know why but after removing jquery.turbolinks the countdown works, however the rest jQuery still do not work.

Comment: you need to share with us the code that isn't working. You likely have code running that isn't working with turbolinks properly

Comment: you could try uninstalling the turbolinks gem and removing the require turbolinks to just check to see if that is your problem..it more than likely is though

Comment: It works after removing turbolinks. But I want to keep it...